# What is the major product of reaction of phenol with HNO3 in the presence of H2SO4?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation, phenols

In many articles I have seen they say the reaction proceeds to picric acid but the amount produced is very small. But the major product is formed by ring cleavage (oxidatively). Can anyone mention the major product and if possible provide the mechanism?

Comment: Without initial sulfonation step, phenol oxidation has many steps and branches..

Comment: Why do you guys keep asking about it? There's no specific product or mechanism. You just get some gunk. Still, it's unlikely to be "ring cleavage" - it's rather oxidative coupling.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dilute nitric acid, you will get mononitrophenol in various proportions depending on phenol/HNO3 molar ratio. Please find yield here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Composition-of-the-products-of-phenol-nitration-with-nitric-acid-in-aqueous-dioxane-in_tbl1_294735990

If you use concentrated nitric acid, the reaction proceeds towards picric acid. See previous discussions:

1. [Does nitration of phenol with nitric acid yields 2,6-dinitrophenol?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173712/does-nitration-of-phenol-with-nitric-acid-yields-2-6-dinitrophenol)
2. [Preparation of picric acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44090/preparation-of-picric-acid)